# Ranking system using a complex query: more precise filters

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, ranking

To realize a ranking system on my gameserver, I store some information about each player in a MySQL database.
I've got the following database tables.

Table `players` with example data:

```
id | steamId | deaths
---+---------+-------
1  | asdja   | 2
2  | kfjsl   | 5
```

Table `weapons` with example data:

```
playerId | weaponId | kills
---------+----------+------
1        | 5        | 8
1        | 9        | 7
2        | 3        | 3
2        | 6        | 10
2        | 7        | 2
```

You see that I do not store the kills for each player in the `players`-table, because I could simply calculate it from the `weapons`-table.
I'm not very familiar with SQL queries, but I finished creating the following one to select a simple data set with following fields:

```
kills,
deaths,
kill-death-rate (kdrate),
count (maximum number of players),
rank (current ranking position, sorted by kills)
```

The query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(weapons.kills) AS `kills`,
    `deaths`,
    (SUM(kills) / IF(deaths, deaths, 1)) AS `kdrate`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `players`) AS `count`,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    p.id AS id2,
                    SUM(w.kills) AS kills2,
                    p.deaths AS deaths2,
                    p.steamId AS steamId2
                FROM
                    weapons AS w,
                    players AS p
                WHERE
                    p.id = w.playerId
                GROUP BY
                    p.id
            ) AS temp
        WHERE
            temp.kills2 >= (
                SELECT
                    SUM(weapons.kills) AS `kills`
                FROM
                    `players`,
                    `weapons`
                WHERE
                    players.id = weapons.playerId AND
                    `id` = 1
                GROUP BY
                  `id`
            )
        ORDER BY
            temp.kills2 DESC,
            temp.deaths2 ASC,
            temp.steamId2 ASC
    ) AS `rank`
FROM
    `players`
INNER JOIN
    `weapons`
ON
    players.id = weapons.playerId
WHERE
    `id` = 1
GROUP BY
    `id`
```

There are two problems:

1.) The query is horrible.

2.) Executing this query with the given example data results in "the same rank".
I mean, both players get the same rank because I the amount of kills is the same on both players.
But instead, player 1 should be on rank 1 because he has less deaths than player 2.
I don't know how I can realize this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
@Manueru_mx gave me a basic idea of how to do it:
I've got the following code based on his answer:

```
SELECT
    id,
    kills,
    deaths,
    kdrate,
    COUNT(*) AS rank,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players) AS `count`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            pys.id AS id,
            SUM(wps.kills) AS kills,
            pys.deaths AS deaths,
            (SUM(wps.kills) / pys.deaths) as kdrate
        FROM
            players pys
        INNER JOIN
            weapons wps
        ON
            pys.id = wps.playerid
        GROUP BY
            pys.id
        ORDER BY
            2 DESC,
            3,
            4 ASC
    ) AS tmp
WHERE
    id = 1
```

The only problem left is, that the `rank` is 1 in both cases.

Comment: I dont get why you have to build that sick query to get the rank. You have all the fields you need, why not just order by them according to your desired ranking and add a "ranking number" in the "code part"?

Comment: Because I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my "solution". This query is more simple but get the results you are looking

```
select 
pys.steamID, SUM(wps.kills) as Kills,
SUM(pys.deaths) as Deaths,
(sum(wps.kills)/sum(pys.deaths)) as kdratio
--,COUNT(pys.steamID) as PlayersC
from players pys
inner join  weapons wps on pys.id = wps.playerid
group by pys.steamID
order by 2 DESC, 3, 4 ASC
```

Add the rank.

```
SELECT
    id,
    kills,
    deaths,
    kdrate,
    ranking_usr as rank,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players) AS `count`
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            @row := @row + 1 AS ranking_usr
            pys.id AS id,
            SUM(wps.kills) AS kills,
            pys.deaths AS deaths,
            (SUM(wps.kills) / pys.deaths) as kdrate
        FROM
            players pys
        INNER JOIN
            weapons wps
        ON
            pys.id = wps.playerid
        GROUP BY
            pys.id
        ORDER BY
            2 DESC,
            3,
            4 ASC
    ) AS tmp
WHERE
    id = 1
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. What do you mean with `PlayersC`? This query doesn't give me the current rank of a player :/

Comment: PlayersC is a mistake i made. Maybe you need how many players kill each player, but it's not possible get that with this info. The query returns a list where every player is ordered by the number of Kills/Deaths. For me is a ranking. Maybe i miss something in the question

Comment: Yeah, that's nice so far. I tried to assimilate it into my needs. You may have a look in my first post, I edited it. This gives me now a single row for one playerId, but the `rank` is wrong :/

Comment: The problem is the Rank value is a simple count of how many rows returns the query. If you need a number like Player X has the rank 4 of 5 users you need to use another aproach. Use @rownum:=@rownum+1 'rank' for rank the results before you filter the ID

Comment: Wow. It works, thanks a lot! I use the version I've posted below. Your solution turns out NULL, not a number.

Comment: Ups, sorry in this pc i don't have mysql installed. sorry. :(

Answer (score 2):

Based on Manueru_mx answer, here's the solution:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        id,
        kills,
        deaths,
        kdrate,
        @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM players) AS `count`
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                pys.id AS id,
                SUM(wps.kills) AS kills,
                pys.deaths AS deaths,
                (SUM(wps.kills) / pys.deaths) as kdrate
            FROM
                players pys
            INNER JOIN
                weapons wps
            ON
                pys.id = wps.playerid
            GROUP BY
                pys.id
            ORDER BY
                2 DESC,
                3,
                4 ASC
        ) AS tmp,
        (SELECT @rownum:= 0) r
    ) AS tmp2
WHERE
    id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the result you are expecting?
You can simple know how many kills a played did by running:

```
select id, (select sum (kills) from weapons where playerid = p.id)
from  players p
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm expecting that player 1 is on rank 1, and player 2 is on rank 2 because he has more deaths than player 1.